# Sum of a general series.

Tags: limits

How we can prove that

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x(x-1)(\frac{\theta}{1+\theta})^{x}=2\theta^{2}(1+\theta)$ where $0<\theta<1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\alpha^k=\alpha^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\alpha^{k-2}=\alpha^2\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha^k\right)^{(2)}=\alpha^2\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\right)^{(2)}$$
so derivate twice  and replace $\alpha$ by $\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$ and you have the result.

Comment: I have to take derivative w.r.t?

Comment: Take the derivative twice with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: When I replace $\alpha=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$ then $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ becomes $1+\theta$ whose twice dervivative w.r.t $\theta$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^k = \frac{1}{1-t}.  $$

Now, differentiate the above series twice.